# delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; does not work in init: only viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, init

I am using a delegate to store data for my app.  I have a tabviewcontroller with a navigationviewcontroller as the first view controller.  When i set the delegate using

```
delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

the delegate is null outside of the init method.
It however works fine when places in viewDidLoad.  Any ideas why this could be?

UPDATE

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Which initialization method(s) are you overriding? The one that's called depends on how the controller is created.

Comment: - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
Also, it was being called, and the delegate is set inside the init method, however if I try and access the delegate outside of the init method(eg, in viewDidLoad) then the delegate is null

Comment: But does it work inside init method? Isn't it null?

Comment: Inside the init method, i can access the delegate yes, but not outside of it.

Comment: Can you show some more code? Do you get any warnings? What is `delegate` in the code that you are showing: an instance variable or a local variable?

Comment: "global instance variable" is a contradiction in terms. Please show the declaration of `delegate`, and consider showing the entire method where the code in question lives.

Comment: Your variable `delegate` has scope local to your init method. You're not assigning it to anything with a bigger scope or longer lifetime than that. At least that's the assumption I draw from the code you've shown--you haven't shown us where you're declaring `delegate` anywhere other than right here.

Comment: In the header file I am declaring it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nib file was calling the initWithCoder method, not init.

Answer (score 1):

Is this view controller in your MainWindow.xib file (or whatever the main .xib in your project is called)? If so, the app delegate is likely also created when that file is loaded, and the app delegate probably is nil at time your view controller is created. If your app delegate has a reference to this view controller, have it set itself as the view controller's delegate in `-applicationDidFinishLoadin:withOptions:`, or just connect the app delegate to the view controller's -delegate outlet in the .xib file.

Comment: It is not MainWindow.xib.  I have created a separate tabBarViewController class which has the tabbar inside of it.  There is also a separate UIViewcontroller for this specific viewcontroller

Comment: Nevertheless, if the view controller in question is being created as the app starts up, the app delegate may not yet be set. If you break on the line where you're trying to assign it, do you actually get a legitimate pointer to the app delegate?

Comment: The view controller is not being created until a button is pressed on the login screen before it.  And yes, in the init method, I get a legitimate pointer to the delegate, I can even access its values.  However after the init method ends I can no longer access delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `-init` method. Sometimes it's not being called. Use theese methods for additional initialization:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // do something
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Can you justify that? There's nothing wrong with initializing your view controller in its initialization method(s); it's just that the controller's view isn't loaded at that point, so initialization that depends on the view should be deferred until `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Yes, I know it works if I use viewDidLoad, but I don't think that is the best practise.  Also, init is being called in this situation

Comment: Ok, this was dumb of me to not realize earlier but if I set the value of a global test string, I can't even access that value outside of the init.  Something very weird is going on